# Set image src to a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an image in my page. I want to change it's src in a script tag.
this is code :

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgSecode" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CImage.aspx" CssClass="lblSec"/>
```

in page CImage , an image will create.
it works.
but when i want to change the picture in script tag,it doesn;t work.
here is javascript code :

```
document.getElementById('<%= ImgSecode.ClientID %>').src = "CImage.aspx";
```

In addition when i set the source to an image which is in solution it works.

Can you help me what should i do?

Comment: `it doesn;t work` is not very helpful. Are you getting any errors in the browser developer console? or the developer network tab? If so, what does the error say

Comment: Try setting it using `document.getElementById('<%= ImgSecode.ClientID %>').setAttribute('ImageUrl', 'CImage.aspx');`

Comment: No there isn't any error in console.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `src='~/CImage.aspx'` ?

Comment: @ParkashKumar this isn not work again.. without any error

Comment: @RayonDabre no src='CImage.aspx' is right  when i put ~/ will get in to an error

Comment: Check your client side generated component and see where this URL is set. Then set that attribute.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, How does that make a difference ? Pls explain ?

Comment: @ParkashKumar i don't understand your mean.would you mind explain ?

Comment: `<asp:Image>` is server side component. It has custom attribute `ImageUrl` which has no sense in simple HTML. In your firebug tool, check element for generated code and find attribute where `~/CImage.aspx` is getting set.

Comment: @ParkashKumar i'msorry but firebug tool?!! i 'm just a beginner in asp and i don't know about firebug.whould you help me?

Comment: Browser tool to view generated source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use strictly JavaScript based solution you need to use `SetAttribute` method like this-

```
document.getElementById("<%=ImgSecode.ClientID %>").setAttribute('src', '<Full Web Path of your Image>');
```

Or if you are open to Jquery as well the use `.attr`.

```
$("[id='ImgSecode']").attr("src", "<Full Web Path of your Image>");
```

Also as per your question setting .aspx to src is by mistake I guess.

Comment: i have done it, but again nothing change.still i have problem